# Solving a recurrence relation without the characteristic equations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am new to solving recurrence relations and I am presented with the following two problems

(1) $$a_n = (3n-1)a_{n-1}, a_0 = 3$$

and

(2) $$a_{n+3}-6a_{n+2} + 11a_{n+1}-6a_{n} = 0, a_0 =1, a_1 =1, a_2 = -2$$

For (1), I try to find a pattern so $a_n = (3n-1)(3(n-1)-1)a_{n-2} = (3n-1)(3n-4)a_{n-2}$ Now do this one more time so we have $a_n = (3n-1)(3n-4)(3n-7)a_{n-4}$ and so we see a pattern emerging

So I just conclude that $$a_n =(3n-1)(3n-4)(3n-7) \dots \times 3$$ But I feel there is something wrong here.

For (2) Let $a_n = cr^n$ where $c,r \neq 0$and then I use the characteristic equation $$r^3 -6r^2 + 11r - 6 = 0 =(r-3)(r-2)(r-1)=0$$

So I have $r=1,2,3$ as the characteristic roots

Now we have $a_n = A(1)^n + B(2)^n + C(3)^n$

$1 = A + B + C$

$1 = A + 2B + 3C$

$-2 = A + 4B + 9C$

And after solving this linear system, I get $$A= \frac{-1}{2}, B=3, C=\frac{-3}{2}$$

And so finally we have that $$a_n = \frac{-1}{2} + 3(2)^n  -\frac{3^{n+1}}{2}, n \geq 0$$

I think I got the second recurrence right, But the first one I don't know how to find it

Comment: You are correct but to make it clear the first one should be $a_n =(3n-1)(3n-4)(3n-7) \dots (5)(2)\times 3$.

Comment: @cr001 What is the least $n$ for this to work and how to argue ? 

For instance This will not make sense of if$n=1,2,3$ right ?

Comment: It is a matter of expression. For example sometimes we say $1+2+3+...+n={n(n+1)\over2}$ but this does not work for $n=1$ as well. To be rigorous you would write $(\prod_{i=1}^{n}(3i-1))\times3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = (3n-1)a_{n-1}=(3n-1)(3n-4)a_{n-2}=...=a_{n-m}\prod_{k=1}^m(3n-3k+2)\\
=a_{n-n}\prod_{k=1}^n(3n-3k+2)=a_0\prod_{k=1}^n(3n-3k+2)$$